# Angular ngFor lifecycle

Tags: angular, ngfor, angular-components, angular-component-life-cycle

I'm using `*ngFor` to iterate some data like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let d of [1, 2, 3]"> {{d}} </div>
```

Everything is fine and I got the result as expected:

```
<div> 1 </div>
<div> 2 </div>
<div> 3 </div>
```

Then, I wondered if I use a function instead of `{{d}}`, so I wrote a function:

```
protected logAndReturn(item) {
    console.log(item);
    return item;
}
```

and I used it:

```
<div *ngFor="let d of [1, 2, 3]"> {{logAndReturn(d)}} </div>
```

I got the same rendered HTML result as the first code, but console output wasn't my expected output.
Console output:

```
1
2
3
1
2
3

Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.

1
2
3
1
2
3
```

The added function was called 12 times now (4 time for each item)

Here is the code that you can test it yourself: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/adh5g4zy/)

Is my code wrong? Is there any solution to prevent these extra calls? Why did this happen and can anybody explain it a little?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using methods in the view is the same that using impure pipes. This code will be executed in each event on the view, which can be a lot of times. In our example, the `logAndReturn()` method only returns a number so it can be assumable to run it in a view but if it would do something more complex, it could be a big problem of performance. with a simple program you can check console.log to see in which step the trace of “logAndReturn” is printed. This is the look of the new component:

```
export class AppComponent implements 
OnChanges,
OnInit,
DoCheck,
AfterContentInit,
AfterContentChecked,
AfterViewInit,
AfterViewChecked,
OnDestroy
{
  private var01: string = "default value";
  constructor( private trans: TranslatorService ){}
  ngOnChanges (){
     console.log('Trace OnChanges');
  }
  ngOnInit (){
     console.log('Trace onInit');
  }
  ngDoCheck (){
     console.log('Trace doCheck');
  }
  ngAfterContentInit(){
     console.log('Trace After Content Init');
  }
  ngAfterContentChecked(){
     console.log('Trace after contente checked');
  }
  ngAfterViewInit(){
     console.log('Trace after view init');
  }
  ngAfterViewChecked(){
     console.log('Trace after view checked');
  }
  ngOnDestroy(){
     console.log('Trace on destroy');
  }
  testRender() {
    console.log('trace 01');
    return 'This is a test that runs a console log'
  }
  (...)
}
```

To go deeper in what really is happening here, read the official documentation of Angular 2 about the [life cycle](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html)

Answer (score 3):

This issue has no relation with `*ngFor`, It's the normal behavior of the `expression` inside the interpolation `({{ }})`. It is called by angular intentionally multiple times to check if the `expression` has changed. Interpolation is meant for fetching (printing) `expressions` and not recomended for calling `methods`. It will fire unnecessarily.

[Issue is with the method inside interploation not *ngFor](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nhttpq)